# Merge 3 dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 similar dataframes that I would like to merge to another larger one. I have 2 ways to assign costs to part numbers (B1_df and B2_df) and would like to assign costs to all the item numbers.

B1_df and B2_df have the same column headers

A_df has the item numbers, and B1_df and B2_df are the ones with costs. result_df is the expected result after the merge.

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show code as text, not images.

Comment: Did you researched pandas `join`, `merge` and `concat`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `pd.concat()`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

```py
result_df = pd.concat([B1_df,B2_df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not take A_df into account and it doesn't assign the costs to the item numbers. How do you use pd.concat to merge A_df to B1_df and B2_df?

Comment: Join on your columns in common after concat. Pandas has straightforward tools for this, like `pd.join()` and `pd.merge()`